# Margin in title page

Tags: titles

I want to decrease the left margin of the University logo without disturbing other things on the title page. I have been using the following code written in .cls file. Present and targeted results are shown in pictures 1 and 2 respectively. Thanks!

[image: Present result]

[image: targeted result]

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{Thesis}
          [2007/22/02 v1.0
 LaTeX document class]
\def\baseclass{book}

\renewcommand\maketitle{
\btypeout{Title Page}
\hypersetup{pdftitle={\@title}}
\hypersetup{pdfsubject=\subjectname}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authornames}
\hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{titlepage}
\let\footnotesize\small
\let\footnoterule\relax
\let \footnote \thanks
\setcounter{footnote}{0}
\null\vfil
\vskip 10\p@  
\begin{titlepage}
    \let\footnotesize\small
    \let\footnoterule\relax
    \let \footnote \thanks
    \setcounter{footnote}{0}
    \null\vfil
    \vskip 10\p@
    \begin{flushleft}
      \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

{\titlehead{\Centering\includegraphics
[width=70mm]{Appendices/images/img.jpg}}}
      \smallskip
      \hline
      {\small Faculty of Environmental Sciences \par}
      \hline
\bigskip
  {\huge \bf \@title \par}
\vfill
\end{flushleft}

\endinput
```

Comment: Could you please post a compilable code, not just a snippet? We don't even know which document class you're using.

Comment: Try `\hspace*{-2cm}\includegraphics
[width=70mm]{Appendices/images/img.jpg}`. Adjust the 2cm to your needs.

Comment: You are using one of the worst classes one could ever use for writing a thesis. Dresden has its own templates, use them.

Comment: @Johannes_B, thanks for your opinion but the professor saw very much satisfied with the work, so for this time, I'll keep it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
\hspace*{-2cm}\includegraphics [width=70mm]{Appendices/images/img.jpg}.
```

Adjust the 2cm to your needs.